# Expected value of joint poisson process?

Tags: stochastic-processes, poisson-process

Ok so I'm pretty stuck on this, even after searching through a bunch of other questions on here that seem very similar.

> Let $\{X(t), t\geqslant0\}$ be a poisson process with rate $\lambda$.
>
> For $0 < s < t, \text{find E}[X(s)X(t)]$.

I have two trains of thought though, one of them being to calculate the joint distribution using the double integral. The other is to use the independent increment ideas, but I'm not sure how to go about it.

I figure that $X(s) \sim \text{Poi}(λs)$ and $X(t-s) \sim \text{Poi}(λ(t-s))$, and obviously $X(t) = X(s) + X(t-s)$.

I then understand that $X(s)$ and $X(t-s)$ are independent. But how can I go from there, figuring out what the distribution of $X(t)$ looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided that a Poisson process observes independent increment, i.e., $X_t-X_s$ is independent from $X_s$ for all $t\ge s\ge 0$, the desired expectation is thus
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\left(X_tX_s\right)&=\mathbb{E}\left[\left(X_t-X_s\right)X_s+X_s^2\right]\\
&=\mathbb{E}\left[\left(X_t-X_s\right)X_s\right]+\mathbb{E}\left(X_s^2\right)\\
&=\mathbb{E}\left(X_t-X_s\right)\mathbb{E}\left(X_s\right)+\mathbb{E}\left(X_s^2\right)\\
&=\lambda\left(t-s\right)\lambda s+\lambda s\left(1+\lambda s\right)\\
&=\lambda s\left(\lambda t+1\right).
\end{align}

Comment: Ah, thank you very much! So just to clarify, you begin by turning the expectation into something that contains (Xt-Xs), then we can split that into two expected values as E[X+Y] = E[X] + E[Y] and then finally we can use the fact that (Xt-Xs) and Xs are independent to split E[(Xt-Xs)Xs] into E[Xt-Xs]*E[Xs] and from here we can just calculate the values? Also, isn't E[Xt-Xs] = λ(t-s) instead of (t-s) and similar for the other expected values?

Comment: @BrandonBarry: My pleasure. You are right! E[X+Y]=E[X]+E[Y] is due to the linearity of expectation, which is unconditionally true. E[XY]=E[X]E[Y] is due to the independence of X and Y. Also, thank you very much for correcting me. I made a fatal mistake to have left behind all $\lambda$'s!! I just fixed my answer. Thank you :-)